# catch subdomain that have exact format

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to catch every hostname that have the exact format:

```
letters(+or)numbers.example.com
```

My regex:

```
$pattern = '/([0-9a-z]*\.)example.net/';
```

It should work like:

```
test2155.example.net // Catch
2155.example.net // Catch
Test2155.example.net // Don't Catch
test2155.example.net655 // Don't Catch
sd@ddfdftest2155.example.net655 // Don't Catch
sd@ddfdftest2155.example.net@655 // Don't Catch
```

How i can do it please?

Comment: Change `*` to `+` and add lookarounds to check if the hostname is surrounded by the separators you want (spaces, limits of the string,...)

Comment: How about `([0-9a-z]+\.)example.net`

Comment: this `[0-9a-z]` won't match `5V444` for the item `5V444.example.net`. Is it considered?

Comment: What to do with `fddf@56.example.net56555` ? Match or not?

Comment: @Jan: @ is a letter or number for you?

Comment: @Nic: Of course not but `56.example.net` could be a partial match here.

Answer (score 3):

You could use

```
([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\Q.example.net\E
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/gSMpbY/1/).

---

Broken down this says

```
([a-zA-Z0-9]+)   # your original expression
\Q.example.net\E # .example.net literally
```

Comment: The word boundaries are useless and doesn't prove anything. Example: `abc-123.example.net`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: OP did not want a dash.

Comment: Indeed, but your pattern will return `123.example.net`.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: What to do with e.g. `fddf@56.example.net56555` then?

Comment: I think the more strong way is to add lookarounds with allowed separators: `(?<!\S)[a-zA-Z0-9]+\Q.example.net\E(?!\S)` (spaces here)

Answer (score 2):

Change the quantifier from `*` to `+` and add word boundary `\b`:

```
/([0-9a-z]+\.)example.net\b
```